Access a operator[] with [1,2,3] results in call to operator[](int)... Is this a bug?
I am attempting at access a class that is like a multidimensional array through the operator[].. only to discover that a comma separated set of parameters is reduced to the first parameter only.. This was a quite a surprise to me..
Does anyone know if this an actual bug or some kind of legalize gotcha in the c++ standard or compiler implementations?..
Its rather annoying as the compiler tends to reduce it without error or warning and bugs can slide by if the coder makes a mistake.
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

template <size_t D, size_t N>
struct A {
    //size_t operator[](int idx) {
    //    throw std::runtime_error("wtf!");
    //}

    size_t operator[](std::initializer_list<int> idx) {
        if (idx.size() != D) {
            throw std::runtime_error("lacking entries");
        }

        size_t offset = 0;
        for (size_t v : idx) {
            offset = offset*N + v;
        }
        return offset;
    }
};

int main() {
    A<3,10> a;    
    std::cout << a[1,2,3] << "\n";    // BUG??
    std::cout << a[{1,2,3}] << "\n";    
}

The godbolt is here: https://godbolt.org/z/WYeGn7Y4n
I expect a[1,2,3] to access the initializer list call and pass all parameters over however it accesses the single parameter one(or tries to)

Ye olde comma operator?

Ye olde comma operator?    yes that is also my first guess as to why its happening well... but it feels really out of place as this should be basically like a function call..

In a[1, 2, 3], the commas are the comma operator, regardless of how you might have defined operator overloads. That's one of the great things about C and C++,  the parsing of an expression does not change based on the details of the function being called. It would really be a nightmare if you couldn't parse an expression without first doing overload resolution and then inspecting the function that wins the resolution ... probably impossible

[C++ ] array operator with multiple arguments?

only to discover that a comma separated set of parameters is reduced to the first parameter only Considering that the comma is read as the comma operator, it should be the last but not the first. I checked in coliru whether I overlooked something, but I didn't - g++ agrees with me. ;-)

As of C++23, this is supported--you can overload operator[] to take multiple parameters, and support multi-dimensional subscripting directly.
Before that, operator[] takes only one parameter, so the 1,2,3 in a[1,2,3] is an expression using the comma operator, so it's equivalent to a[3] (the 1 is evaluated, then discarded, then the 2 is evaluated, it's discarded, finally the 3 is evaluated and becomes the result of the expression).
You can create overloads to support a[1][2][3] if you really want to, but it's a lot easier to overload operator() for an arbitrary number of parameters (or, as noted above, use C++23 instead).
Here's a sample of doing the a[1][2][3] thing, if you care to consider that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76808189/179910

Ahh yes i see.. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Array_subscript_operator

The c++23 example cited has a fixed number of arguments (3); does c++23 also allow versions with unknown number of arguments ? This topic could do with a canonical Q/A since (if the answer to my question is Yes), it is a breaking change

@M.M It's a known breaking change. The proposal specifically checked for breakage and found pretty much nothing.
